# Как правильно объявить переменную-итератор из std? C++

Tags: c++, массивы, итераторы

У меня есть массив из std `std::array<buffer_type, buffer_size> buffer;`. Он представляет собой, как понятно, буфер. Мне нужно хранить переменную, которая указывала бы на какую-либо позицию в этом буфере. Как правильно объявить такую переменную? Я попробовал сделать так:

```
std::array<buffer_type, buffer_size> buffer;
std::array<buffer_type, buffer_size>::const_iterator current_symbol;
```

Компилятор не ругается, но у меня стойкое ощущение, что я делаю что-то не так. Можно ли как-то сократить эту огромную строку? Или же есть другой способ записи?

Upd: Буфер и итераторы - это переменные-члены пользовательского класса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько способов. Обычно, сейчас никто не переживает и использует auto для таких целей.

```
auto current_symbol = buffer.cbegin();
```

и все готово. Плюс такого способа очевиден - переменная всегда инициализирована и ее тип автоматом будет определен компилятором. Но иногда хочется большего. В этом случае я обычно делаю так

Вначале объявляю свой тип

```
using my_buffer = std::array<buffer_type, buffer_size>;
```

теперь можно написать вот так

```
my_buffer buffer;
```

или так

```
my_buffer::const_iterator current_symbol;
```

или даже сделать так

```
using my_buffer_citer = my_buffer::const_iterator;
my_buffer_citer  current_symbol;
```

но auto для итераторов сейчас чуть ли не стандарт.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я только забыл добавить, что и буфер, и итератор - это переменные-члены у класса, поэтому auto мне не поможет. В итоге я все верно делаю и выход - только использование псевдонимов?

Comment: м, нужно прям объявить? ну тогда using/typedef в помощь. И не нужно будет постоянно писать такое длинное. Если тип поменяется - все автоматом заведется. Если дать имена красивые (что бы пользователь этого класса не понимал деталей реализации), то будет очень удобно. В будущем можно будет подменить реализацию и никто не заметит.